# How to Modified X axis lables in SSRS chart or add expression to X axis lables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I making SSRS chart Line report.

Default values generated from Query as it is displayed on CHART of X axis labels.

**How to Modified this X-axis labels ?**

```
--- Default  current X Axis values: Years

2013.00     2013.25    2013.50     2013.75    2014.00
```

I want in report (Expected O/p)

```
2013Q1  2013Q2 2013Q3  2013Q4  2014Q1
```

OR

```
-- Skip mid years having points like .25, .50 or .75

2013                                          2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled in SQL query.

```
concat(Datepart(YYYY,DateCol),'_Q',Datepart(QQ,DateCol)) Year
```

open Horizontal Axis Property and set `interval` `Property=1`